# jquery .on() with multiple events AND passing arbitrary data

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I know you can pass multiple events to `.on()` like so:

```
$(".myThing").on({
     mousedown:mouseDownFunction,
     mouseup:mouseUpFunction
});
```

...and I know you can pass arbitrary data along with `.on()`, like so:

```
$(".myThing").on("click",{myParam:5},clickFunction);
```

But is there syntax to define multiple events while also passing arbitrary data?  I'm not seeing how to do that in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass data as the second optional parameter:

```
$(".myThing").on({
     mousedown: mouseDownFunction,
     mouseup: mouseUpFunction
}, {myParam: 5});
```

Then inside of the event handlers you will be able to access this data as `e.data.myParam`, where `e` is a parameter (instance of an [event object](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)) of the invoked event handler function.